# How to read return value of mmap

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, memory-address

I'm new to this topic, I have mmaped 3 pages. How can I read the content of each? I know I have to use PAGE_SHIFT but I don't know how.

```
unsigned int* address = mmap(...)
```

Comment: `unsigned int i = address[0]` -- What's the problem?..

Comment: how can I get the start address of second page?

Comment: It depends on architecture you've used. As for `x86`, `PAGE_SIZE` is 4096. So the page contains `PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int)` items and `page0` refers to `&address[0]`, `page1` refers to `&address[1024]` and `page2` refers to `&address[2048]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethings like following...

```
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096

unsigned int * address = mmap(...)

unsigned int * page0 = &address[ 0 * PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int) ];
unsigned int * page1 = &address[ 1 * PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int) ];
unsigned int * page2 = &address[ 2 * PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int) ];
```

Comment: Thanks can you please explain it?

Comment: `PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int)` gives you amount of `int` items per page. So the first (zero indexed) item of each page has address like `&address[ N *  items_per_page]`, where `N` is the page index.